# Deploy a sub-directory from Travis CI to OpenShift

Tags: openshift, travis-ci

I'm looking to deploy an app through Travis CI to OpenShift. Currently I have it setup so that Travis CI will run my build (in this case, an Ember CLI application) into a /dist folder. Is there any way to deploy just that /dist folder? Or am I SOL and should just figure out how to route traffic to the subfolder?

Comment: Openshift requires a git repo to deploy, and since you can't create a git repo inside of a git repo, I'd say you're most likely SOL, though you might be able to find some workaround.

Comment: Hey @joshua-anderson, thanks for the reply. I figured I was SOL, so I've gone down the route of configuring a fairly simple node server to route requests appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Well have a look to 
[Travis + Openshift Not deploying to openshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706304/travis-openshift-not-deploying-to-openshift/28707731#28707731)

```
after_success:
- grunt build
- cd dist
- git init
- git config --global user.email "travis@localhost.localdomain"
- git config --global user.name "Travis CI"
- git add --all
- git commit -am "Travis change"
```

Seems to answer your question, I haven't tested it myself.